# Laravel cannot retrieve data using one to many not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem with one to many relationship in Laravel. I cannot retrieve my data from database. My codes are following.

**Doctor.php**

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}
```

**City.php**

```
public function doctor()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Doctor');
}
```

**view**

```
@foreach($doctors as $doctor)
    <tr>
        <td data-title="ID">{{ $doctor->id }}</td>
        <td data-title="Name">{{ $doctor->name }}</td>
        <td data-title="Hospital">{{ $doctor->hospital }}</td>
        <td data-title="Designation">{{ $doctor->designation  }}</td>
        <td data-title="City">{{ $doctor->cities->name }}</td> <!-- problem in this line -->
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

When I try to view the data an error has been shown:

> ErrorException in 3d7f581c490d492093e6e73f8ebd29525504e56b.php line 46:
>
> Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\tourisms\root\resources\views\doctors\index.blade.php)

Comment: Could you check the query that is constructed by `$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries); echo $last_query;` and see it in phpmyadmin to see what query is actually created ?

Comment: Do you have any doctors that have no city related to them?

Comment: No. All doctor has city. @Laerte

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Where should I try this code?

Comment: In your controller , i.e., after you construct this array `doctors`

Comment: How are you retrieving your doctors? Are you loading the relationship? `Doctor::with('cities')->get()`

Comment: Can you show your Doctor and Citites schemas please?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I tried. It returns `false`

Answer (score 2):

On the `belongsTo` side of the relationship, when the foreign key name is not specified, it is built using the name of the relationship. In this case, since your relationship is named `cities`, Laravel will look for the field `doctors.cities_id`.

If your foreign key is not `cities_id`, then you need to either change the name of your relationship method, or specify the name of the foreign key:

```
public function cities() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City', 'city_id');
}

// or, better:

public function city() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}
```

Also, as mentioned by @Christophvh, the naming of your relationships is a little off, but not programmatically incorrect. It makes more sense and is more readable when `belongsTo`/`hasOne` relationships are named singular, and `belongsToMany`/`hasMany` relationships are named plural.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to loop a Collection and not an array.

2 solutions:

1)
 add ->get(); when you are calling your relationship in your controller

2)
 use

```
 @foreach($doctors->all() as $doctor)
```

instead of

```
@foreach($doctors as $doctor)
```

**Also a quick tip:**
Your naming is not really telling what you are doing. You should swap them around like below. 'A doctor belongs to a **city**' & 'A city has many **doctors**'

**Doctor.php**

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}
```

**City.php**

```
public function doctors()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Doctor');
}
```

Comment: The first part is not correct. You can loop over a Laravel `Collection` using `foreach`. The Laravel `Collection` implements the [`IteratorAggregate`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) interface, which extends the [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface, which allows for use in `foreach`.